# Android-How should I handle a thread when the screen is turned off by the user?

Tags: android, multithreading, lifecycle

I have a thread other than my main thread that I am trying to handle correctly during lifecycle events and things the user may do. I made the lifecycle events work by doing the following:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
        thread = new LemonadeMainMenuThread(holder, ctx, new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message m) {
            }
        });
    }
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

This works fine for whenever the user presses the home button then restarts, however if the user press the power button(not off just to sleep) the thread seems to stop as what it does stops happening. What is the correct way to handle the thread when the screen is turned off by the user? As always, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to use `ACTION_SCREEN_ON/ACTION_SCREEN_OFF BroadcastReceiver` for handling Thread